# how to fetch all the news titles from link and store it in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have following link from which I want to scrape the news headlines

`https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2017/11/1/archivelist/year-2017,month-11,starttime-43040.cms`

I am doing following in r

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2017/11/1/archivelist/year-2017,month-11,starttime-43040.cms"

results <- url %>%
read_html() %>%
html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div[1]/table[1]')
```

But there is no data in `results`. I want to put these news in R dataframe.
how can I do it in `R`?

Comment: by headlines you mean the text which reads 
'Not the same old Kochi anymore' etc..

Comment: @hardik Yes. I mean the same thing.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: @Neil Didn't the below answers work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css selector `a` inside `span` to get those headlines - if you want a simpler code and then do your operations on it.

Code:

```
library(rvest)
url = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2017/11/1/archivelist/year-2017,month-11,starttime-43040.cms"

results <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('span a') %>% html_text()

results
```

Output:

```
    > results
      [1] "Not the same old Kochi anymore"                                                                    
      [2] "Ramu Chellappa’s next to be based in Coimbatore"                                                   
      [3] "Old is gold, cream n’ gold"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
library(rvest)

url = "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/2017/11/1/archivelist/year-2017,month-11,starttime-43040.cms"
page <- read_html(url)

titles <- html_text(html_nodes(page,'.cnt div td:nth-child(1) span a'))
titles[1:5]

  > titles[1:5]
[1] "Not the same old Kochi anymore"                                 "Ramu Chellappa’s next to be based in Coimbatore"               
[3] "Old is gold, cream n’ gold"                                     "Meme and troll pages play catalysts in promoting Kannada pride"
[5] "Thallu, Kidu, Oola... Creativity had no bounds in Slangyalam"
```

Comment: How did you find `.cnt div td:nth-child(1) span a` ?